# Выравнивание элементов меню bootstrap 4

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap4, navigation

Расположить по центру элементы меню - не получается
[Скриншот](https://prnt.sc/tkmox4)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <!-- Контейнер (определяет ширину компонента Navbar) -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Бренд и кнопка «Гамбургер» -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Анонимные Наркоманы Днепр"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-example" aria-controls="navbar-example" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <!-- Основная часть меню (может содержать ссылки, формы и другие элементы) -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-example">
      <!-- Этот блок расположен слева -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link " href="#">
                        О нас <span class="sr-only">(текущая)</span>
                    </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Новости</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Группы АН В Днепре
                    </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Только сегодня </a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Нечего бояться</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">ДОМАШНЯЯ НA Днепре</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Полезное</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- Этот блок расположен справа -->
      <div class="navbar-text phone text-center my-2 my-lg-0">
        <h4>Телефон в Днепре</h4>
        <h3><a href="tel:+380950481802">+38 095 04 818 02</a></h3>
        <p>Ответ на любой вопрос по нашей теме</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><a href="mailto:na.ua.dnepr@gmail.com">na.ua.dnepr@gmail.com</a></button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Списку:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto ">
```

Добавьте ml-auto

Comment: Огромное, Вам, спасибо!!!!!!!!